# How to develop a music streaming website using PHP

Tags: php, web, audio

I am about to start a Music Streaming website. I want to provide users to play songs online.
So how to start

1. Where should i store all the music files for faster streaming
2. How to play audio songs on my website
3. For playing a audio file is there any other PROTOCOL to follow ?
4. Is there any frameworks are there ?

Please guide me

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you don't mind paying for the transfer, store all of the files using a cloud storage service. There are many options, to name a few: Amazon S3, Rackspace Cloud Storage, even Google is launching its own storage solution.
2. The easiest way to do this is with a flash player that are freely available through open-source solutions. One of the more popular player is the JW Player - available at http://www.longtailvideo.com/
3. Playing audio can happen as mentioned above in the player or through the new HTML5 audio tags. You have multiple choices here.
4. There are no *frameworks* for building this exact type of app you've described. But there are a number of PHP frameworks out there. Check out Cake PHP, Zend, and CodeIgniter to get started.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you: can i use wordpress?

Comment: Wordpress is a great place to start if you're just beginning. There are a number of audio player plugins that you will be very happy with.

Comment: Okay i'll go with wordpress. Thank You

Answer (score 3):

1. Look to store the files on Amazon S3. It's by far your most cost effective option. http://aws.amazon.com/s3/
2. Use flash http://wpaudioplayer.com/ or html5 audio tag http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_audio.asp
3. Just use http.
4. See #1 and #2

Answer (score 0):

use flash for audio playbacks.
protocol - http is enough